# Universal windows app, Method name expected?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, win-universal-app

I have been trying to add some validation steps while creating a listing in my app but keep getting the error message: Method name expected. I can't figure out where the issue is. Following are the written codes written.

```
 private async void BtnCreateListings_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
      // details about creating the listings
    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtPodName.Text))
     {
       if (idx != -1 )
     {
           POD newPOD = new POD { Name = txtPodName.Text, POD_Type = (PODType)idx };
        POD result = await App._client.CreatePODAsync(newPOD);
         }
          else
          {
          MessageDialog md = new MessageDialog("Error!!! Please Select a Type");
            await md();
          }
       }
        else
       {
          MessageDialog md = new MessageDialog("Error!!! Please Enter a Valid Name");
          await md();
        }
       }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that the error is occurring on the lines

`await md();`.

You should be calling it as

`await md.ShowAsync();`